# How to solve that on quasar framework?

Tags: node.js, quasar-framework

I'm getting this issue on console when starting my quasar application:

"app.js?t=1709137507895:30 Feature flag _*VUE_PROD_HYDRATION_MISMATCH_DETAILS*_ is not explicitly defined. You are running the esm-bundler build of Vue, which expects these compile-time feature flags to be globally injected via the bundler config in order to get better tree-shaking in the production bundle."

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.